# cant re render react class component

Tags: reactjs, typescript, webpack, webpack-5

im using webpack 5.11.1 and react 17.0.2 for my front end
everything seems to work properly except i cant re render CartPopupComponent

index.tsx

```
import React from "react";
import { render } from "react-dom";
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Switch, Route } from "react-router-dom";
import { Top } from "./views/user/layout/top";
import { MainComponent } from "./views/user/main/main";
import { Bottom } from "./views/user/layout/bottom";
import { CartPopupComponent } from "./views/user/layout/cartPopup";

render(
  <Router>
    <Switch>
      <Route path="/" exact>
        <>
          <Top />
          <MainComponent />
          <Bottom />
        </>
      </Route>
    </Switch>
  </Router>,
  document.getElementById("r"),
  () => {
     render(<CartPopupComponent />, document.querySelector("#cartPopup"));
  }
);
```

now on MainComponent i want to re render CartPopupComponent onclick

```
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

<button
                            title="Add to cart"
                            name={x.id.toString()}
                            onClick={() => {
                              x.quantity = 1;
                              x.subProduct = "g50";
                              addToCart(x);
                              ReactDOM.render(<CartPopupComponent />, document.querySelector("#cartPopup");
                              );
                            }}
                          >
```

but this doesn't work

Comment: This is *very* odd. You are rendering three separate and distinct react apps here. (the one with the `<Router>` and two `<CartPopupComponent>`s. Then once you click something in one of those apps you are trying to re-render the root node of the other apps. Is this approach intentional? Or did you mean to make one react app that has all content inside of that? Because this approach of making multiple mounted react apps work together is going to be very difficult for you.

Comment: im doing this because i want to render CartPopupComponent after MainComponent. i believe the code need improvements maybe i shouldt use same component for two popup pages. but still how i can re render CartPopupComponent?

Comment: Generally, for re-rendering multiple componenets I use Context.  You should study that concept and implement it.  A Context is a wrapper over your multiple components that you want to render each time that context changes.  So look for "Context Provider".  Good tutorial I used: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-share-state-across-react-components-with-context

Comment: thanks. i have improve the code now and remove the unnecessary render

Comment: "i want to render CartPopupComponent after MainComponent." Why does it matter what order things render. React rendering is declarative, which means you show it what you want and react renders it for you. "before" or "after" shouldn't make any difference.